# nibernate call mysql stored procedure

Tags: nhibernate, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with two parameters that returns an int.

my mapping.hbm.xml

```
    <sql-query name="CreateAttribute">
        <query-param name="idAttrType" type="int"/>
        <query-param name="idSystemUser" type="int"/>
        call CreateAttribute :idAttrType,:idSystemUser
    </sql-query>
```

C# usage

```
    var t = session.GetNamedQuery("CreateAttribute");
    t.SetInt32("idAttrType", 12);
    t.SetInt32("idSystemUser",int.Parse(id));
    var result = t.List();
```

Then i receive the folowing:

[SQL: call CreateAttribute ?p0,?p1] ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Should it not be:-

```
   <sql-query name="CreateAttribute">
        <query-param name="idAttrType" type="int"/>
        <query-param name="idSystemUser" type="int"/>
        call CreateAttribute(:idAttrType,:idSystemUser);
    </sql-query>
```

Notice the braces around the params.

**edit** run this against your MySql database, does it run?

```
call CreateAttribute(0,0);
```

Comment: Tried it. Now I get an : PROCEDURE sampledb.CreateAttribute does not exist

Comment: Just to be clear, the inline sql I am trying to replace is:      INSERT INTO Misc VALUES (CreateAttribute(12,$userid),$userid, '$title', '$details', '$startdate', '$enddate' , '$isongoing','$xml');". Obviously I will break down the statement into 2 parts , one to call the procedure and one for the Insert

Comment: call CreateAttribute(0,0); --> PROCEDURE sampledb.CreateAttribute does not exist

Comment: So Stored Proc does not exist on the database? You need to create it first!

Answer (score 0):

Modified the call as following
SELECT call CreateAttribute(0,0); -- it worked

new mapping now is

```
    <sql-query name="CreateAttribute">
       <query-param name="idAttrType" type="int"/>
       <query-param name="idSystemUser" type="int"/>
       select CreateAttribute(:idAttrType,:idSystemUser);
    </sql-query>
```

Comment: I am intrigued by this as I only use `call SP_NAME(param);` to call a MySql Sp, can you post your actual stored procedure?

Comment: As it turned out CreateAttribute(,) is a function not a procedure so it can only be used within the context of another statement (in this case SELECT).